# How to handle 'empty' namespace while parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm confused by what the `xmlns=""` attribute in the `articleDoc` element does. I would think that the subelements of `articleDoc` don't have a namespace and can be queried with XPath without it. But XPath does not find them. Using the `w3.org`-namespace, that is declared in the root element does also not work.

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as tree

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>1</id>
  <title>Example XML</title>
  <published>2021-12-15T00:00:00Z</published>
  <updated>2022-01-06T12:44:47Z</updated>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <articleDoc xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaVersion="1.8" xml:lang="en">
      <articleDocHead>
        <itemInfo>my info</itemInfo>
      </articleDocHead>
    </articleDoc>
  </content>
</entry>"""
ns = {'nitf': 'http://iptc.org/std/NITF/2006-10-18/',
      'w3': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
      'xml': 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'}
root = tree.fromstring(xml)
id = root.find("w3:id", ns).text # works
print(id)
type_attribute = root.find("w3:content", ns).attrib['type'] # works


# here's what I've tried so far:
# root.find("itemInfo", ns)
# root.find("articleDoc/itemInfo", ns)
# root.find("w3:articleDoc/itemInfo", ns)
# root.find("w3:itemInfo", ns)
# root.find("itemInfo")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For example `itemInfo` is not an immediate child of the root element. `root.find(".//itemInfo")` should work.